# iPad crashes when trying to share by taping a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

I'm using this code to share a defined string by taping a `UIButton`:

```
@IBAction func shareApp(sender: UIButton) {
    let textToShare = "Look at this:"

    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "www.example.con") {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

That works very well on iPhone and iPad.

Now, I want to do the same, but using `UIBarButtonItem` instead of `UIButton`. Of cause, This code doesn't work for UIBarButtonItem.

Changing `@IBAction func shareApp(sender: AnyObject) {` and `activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView` causes a crash on `iPad's` as soon as I tap on the BarButtonItem.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For iPad in addition to source view for popoverPresentationController, you would also need to add sourceRect as well.
Try the following:

```
 if ( UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad) {

     if let fromView = sender as? UIView {
              youActivityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = fromView

    youActivityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = fromView.frame
}
}
```

Comment: I'll check it out and get back.

Comment: Hi @luckystars, sorry for my late reply. Your solution didn't help. I updated my question. Please take a look at it. Can you help me?